# Distinct query in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, select, distinct

I have a document `(name, firstName, age)`.

This command gives me the different names of the document:

```
db.getCollection('persons').distinct("name")
```

How do I do to get the corresponding firstNames?

Thanks!

Comment: what error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an aggregation query which groups the name and firstName. Eventually you could also add a count to it to see which combinations are repeated (but that is not necessary).

Here is an example:

```
db.test1.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {_id: {name: "$name", firstName: "$firstName"}, count: {$sum: 1}}
        }
    ]
)
```

Here is another another option to show an aggregated list:

```
db.test1.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {_id: {name: "$name"}, firstName: { $push: "$firstName" }}
        }
    ]
)
```